# Como cerrar una ventana de anuncio en selenium con python.?

Tags: python, selenium, scraping

Estoy realizando un proyecto con python y selenium para descargar un archivo desde la pagina:

https://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/?commodity=palm-oil&months=120

Al final de la pagina, debajo de la tabla de datos esta el boton de exportar a excel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar el scraping, tengo lo siguiente

```
driver.get('https://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/?commodity=palm-oil&months=120')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div/div[5]/a').click()
```

Pero al realizar estos pasos  el navegador, me esta abriendo una ventana de anuncio, como la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo inspeccione la pagina y obtuve el Xpath del botón close:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dismiss-button"]').click()
```

La cual me genera error en python que no halla el elemento, y creo que esto se debe a que sigo en la misma pagina y no en la pagina en el anuncio.  Mi pregunta es como podría cerrar la pagina de anuncio sin generar el error y descargar el archivo.

este es el error en python:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Inteté simular la prueba pero me sale un login

Comment: Por favor añada su código para que podamos reproducirlo y ayudarte.